# VS2017: boost binaries with WinXP support?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2017

I've recently upgraded Visual Studio from 2013 (msvc-12.0) to 2017 (msvc-14.1), and updated boost to 1.66 to take advantage of the prebuilt binaries. However I do have projects that need to support Windows XP, and I found this note at https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/

```
1.59.0/ - support of msvc-14.0 (libraries built with msvc-14.0 do not support windows XP)
```

What are my options? Do I need to build my own XP binaries somehow (e.g. with v141_xp toolset)?  I have no experience with building boost, so if it's necessary, any pointers to configuring it would be appreciated.

---

As an aside, I've tried compiling with 1.66 binaries anyway, and naturally got lots of linker errors like the following: (note the v2s_mt_nt5 namespace)

```
5>ImageRegisterLib.lib(testDefs.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::once_block_sentry::rollback(void)" (?rollback@once_block_sentry@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@AAEXXZ)
5>ImageRegisterLib.lib(testDefs.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: bool __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::once_block_sentry::enter_once_block(void)const " (?enter_once_block@once_block_sentry@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@ABE_NXZ)
5>ImageRegisterLib.lib(testDefs.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static unsigned int __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_name::get_id_from_string(char const *)" (?get_id_from_string@attribute_name@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@CAIPBD@Z)
5>ImageRegisterLib.lib(testDefs.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_name __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::default_attribute_names::message(void)" (?message@default_attribute_names@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@YA?AVattribute_name@345@XZ)

(about 100 more similar errors)
```

It seems that boost::log is the only library I need that throws these errors, at least for now.  Others such as filesystem seem to link just fine.  I can resolve these if I change my defines from:

```
#ifndef WINVER
#define WINVER 0x0501   //XP
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 //XP
#endif
```

to:

```
#ifndef WINVER
#define WINVER 0x0600   //Vista
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600 //Vista
#endif
```

But of course this loses XP support.  I'm hoping there's a way to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Just switch to a better log engine...

Comment: may I ask what's wrong with it?

Comment: Heavy and clunky and finicky. The binaries you downloaded won't support XP, you need to build your own with _WIN32_WINNT=0x501 or alternatively (better?) BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION=0x501.

Comment: You may have to use an older toolset as well (both for boost and for your own code)  in addition to defining BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION.

Comment: thanks, I'll give that a try if I couldn't ditch boost::log.

Comment: Just double check my spelling ;) I recently switched from boost log to spdlog.